# Is there any better solution than containers with many dimensions for complex data management?

Tags: c++, json, data-structures

For a musical software I'm currently writing, I need to store a lot of data at different depth into a table (5 dimension container). When I say a lot of data, it doesn't mean that those are heavy (it's mostly small strings and numbers) but there can be a lot of those. The data must be quick to recall when the software needs it, quick to store as well. What would be the best solution for this?

The first version of the software was written in Lua, and I could do this easily (thanks to flexible Lua tables). In `C++`, it would result in a 5 dimension vector, which doesn't seem really convenient to manage. I tried a [JSON parser](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) which didn't seem quick enough. I also thought about the SQL solution, but the current `SQLite` implementation I use (with sqlite3) doesn't really correspond to the data architecture I want. Also, it made me think about some questions about my strategy: is it a good practice in software to write "live" data (I mean data the software uses at runtime and must manipulate sometimes) on disk (like `SQLite` solution, or `JSON`) ? I guess as long as it's not too heavy in memory there's no need of this? And the reverse question: if it's a solution to write on disk, how much performance does it costs?

My last try was to write a multidimensional vector, but I'm not really sure how to initialize this. Every nested vector must be able to resize, and I need to put some data at any depth at any time.

```
std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < const char *> > > > data; 

//The following line obviously doesn't really work, since no vector initialization was done. But a solution working almost like this would be perfect : 
data[c_seq][track_idx][lin][col]=value;
```

The last line causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: Without any information about the data you're storing other than variable names in that last line this question is very broad. I feel like you would be happier with a container of structures and `std::string` instead of `const char*`.

Comment: what is the type of the data, _char_ ? Using a `const char*` you cannot modify just _one_ element of the dimension 5. Before to access `data[c_seq][track_idx][lin][col]` you can first resize _data_ then `data[c_seq]` etc when needed, but are you sure of what you do ? why all these dims ? Out of that your question contains _several_ questions, making the overall too broad

Comment: Thank you both. I recognize the question contains multiple interrogations. 
To be more precise about "why all these dims ?" : I've got several spreadsheet displayed on the screen, each one represents a "musical track". They all contain lines and columns. This is for one "sequence", because if I change the sequence number, it refreshes all the spreadsheets with the new sequences data. So, I need 4 dimensions.  And the question is broad, since i'm trying to figure if the container option is the best one in my case.

Comment: Let me see if I got it: 1. You have several sequences available – and the user can choose from (and possibly even create new ones...). 2. Each sequence can contain arbitrary number of tracks. 3. If user selects a sequence, all the tracks of that one shall show up in spread-sheets. One sheet per track? 4. Now what is the data to be stored at [lin][col]? Will the data be (semantically) equal for each track, i. e. always e. g. "title", "author", "duration", ...?

Comment: You got it ! 
There is one sheet per track. Another thing : the number of columns for each track can vary between sequences (the number of lines is the same for each track, but can vary between sequences as well). The data to be stored are always stored as strings (even if they are numbers) and do not always correspond to the same signature. They correspond to instructions to be passed to a synthesizer. 
In fact, for those who know, that's the base of a musical tracker (but the columns size can vary) : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracker_(musique)

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work with two structs (I didn't test it with large amount of data, but it seems to work fine with small sequences). I created an instance of ScoreData in the spread sheet manager, and here it is.
Thanks for answers !

```
struct TrackData {
    TrackData(int lin=8,int col=8) {
        resize(lin,col);
    }

    void setValueAt(int l, int c,std::string val) {
        if(c<=colnbr && l<=lignbr) {
            data[l][c]=val;
        }
    }

    std::string getValueAt(int l,int c) {
        if(c<=colnbr && l<=lignbr) {
            if(data[l][c].size()==0) return "NULL";
            return data[l][c];
        }
    }

    void resize(int lin, int col) {
        if(lin<=0 || col<=0) return;
        if(lin!=lignbr) {
            lignbr=lin;
            data.resize(lin);
        }
        if(colnbr!=col) {
            colnbr=col;
            for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++) data[i].resize(col);
        }
    }
    void setNumcol(int col) {resize(lignbr,col);}
    void setNumlin(int lin) {resize(lin,colnbr);}

    std::vector < std::vector < std::string> > data;
    int colnbr;
    int lignbr;
};

struct ScoreData {
    ScoreData(int seq, int track) {
        resize(seq,track);
    }

    void resize(int seq,int track) {
        if(seq<=0 || track <=0) return;
        if(seq!=seqnbr) {
            seqnbr=seq;
            data.resize(seqnbr);
        }
            tracknbr=track;
            for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++) data[i].resize(track);
    }

    void setValueAt(int seq,int track,int lin,int col,std::string val) {
        if(seq>=0 && seq<seqnbr && track >=0 && track <tracknbr) {
            data[seq][track].setValueAt(lin,col,val);
        }
    }

    std::string getValueAt(int seq,int track,int lin, int col) {
        if(seq>=0 && seq<seqnbr && track >=0 && track <tracknbr) {
            return data[seq][track].getValueAt(lin,col);
        }
    }

    void setNumlin(int seq,int lin) {
        for(int i=0;i<data[seq].size();i++) data[seq][i].setNumlin(lin);
    }

    void setNumcol(int seq,int track,int col) {data[seq][track].setNumcol(col);}
    void setNumtrack(int track) {resize(seqnbr,track);}
    void setNumseq(int seq) {
        resize(seq,tracknbr);
    }

    std::vector < std::vector < TrackData > > data;
    int seqnbr;
    int tracknbr;
};
```